# R 2.15.0 lm() on Windows 6.1.7601 - Subsetting data frame receive error when labeling columns

Tags: r, statistics, subset

Purpose: Subset a dataframe into 2 columns that are labeled with new names
for example:

```
   Age Height
1  65  183
2  73  178

[data1[dataset1$Age>50 | dataset1$Height>140,], c("Age","Cm")]
# Error: unexpected ',' in "data1[data1$Age>50 | data1$Height>140,],"
```

What I've tried:

```
data1[dataset1$Age>50 | dataset1$Height>140,] #This doesn't organize results in columns
data1[dataset1$Age>50 | dataset1$Height>140,], c("Age","Cm") #Returns same error
```

I can't get the columns to be organized side-by-side with the labels in c("label1", "label2"). Thanks for your help! New to R and learning it alongside biostats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have missed what you were trying to do need a bit more reproducible data I think.

Nevertheless I had a go

```
dataset1 = data.frame(cbind((35:75),(135:175)))
colnames(dataset1) = c("Age","Height")

Age Height
35  135
36  136
37  137
38  138
39  139
40  140
41  141
42  142
43  143
44  144
```

and subset

```
data1 = dataset1[dataset1$Age>50 | dataset1$Height>140,]
colnames(data1) = c("Age","Cm")

Age Cm
41  141
42  142
43  143
44  144
45  145
46  146
47  147
48  148
49  149
50  150
```

My apologies if I missed what you wanted but to me it wasn't very clear.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, this works. I'm sorry for not making it clear, but you solved my issue - so thanks!

Comment: @user3068408 Gday mate, could you accept the answer that helped you out? glad to here it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If I got it clearly can subset function be of help

```
dataset1 <- data.frame(
   age=c(44,77,21,55,66,90,23,54,31),
   height=c(144,177,121,155,166,190,123,154,131)
)

data1 <- as.data.frame(subset(dataset1,dataset1$age>50 | dataset1$height>140))
                  colnames(data1) <- c("Age", "Height")
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried the above recommended solution and this one, and they both seem to work. Thanks for your help.